# Creating a view with a case

Tags: mysql

I keep getting errors with the code but cannot see why. I'm very new to mysql so apologies in advance.

I want to pull data from a table and perform several cases on the data but I keep getting errors. Could anyone help me what i'm doing wrong.

```
  CREATE VIEW myView3 AS (
  SELECT 
    freight,
    DATEDIFF(now(),shipping_date) AS days_in_transit,
    DATEDIFF(now(),shipping_date) AS transit_status
    CASE 
    WHEN transit_status > 5 then "Problem"
    ELSE "In transit"
    END
  FROM tracking
);
```

The code works fine when I remove the case

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a comma after DATEDIFF(now(),shipping_date) AS transit_status, but I'm wondering if you think the view will have 3 or 4 columns returned, when you add the comma, it will have 4, the CASE statement will not replace the DATEDIFF value with "problem" or "In transit" as I suspect you  expect.

Comment: I added the comma, but I now get the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'transit_status' in 'field list' - you are correct though - i'm only after 3 columns but still can't get the case column working

Comment: Thank you!!, that's solved it

Comment: Please share more details, like all error messages in text form

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the definition of your View

```
CREATE VIEW myView3 AS (
SELECT 
  freight,
  DATEDIFF(now(),shipping_date) AS days_in_transit,
  CASE
    WHEN 
    (DATEDIFF(now(),shipping_date) > 5) then "Problem" 
  ELSE 
    "In transit"
  END
     As transit_status
FROM tracking
);
```